# JVC Clock Question

Tags: audio

I have one question and no one can seem to give me a straight answer, all I would like to know is: for my JVC; model KW-R930BTS car stereo does the power need to be on to see the clock?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you asking if the vehicle is turned off (key in the "off" position, possibly removed), should the clock be viewable on your JVC head unit?

Answer (score 1):

The [manual for your radio](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1343969/Jvc-Kd-R995bts.html?page=5#manual) says there is a setting to control whether the clock is displayed when the unit is off.

It shows something like this (which was from a PDF I can't link to). See the **CLOCK DISPLAY** section.

[image]

You can search for and download the clearer PDF quite easily.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I saw that in the directions. But it is not working on my radio I have to turn the unit on.

Comment: Do you mean you change the setting, and it still won't show the time when you switch it off?

Comment: Also I don't know how you had it installed but if this isn't working I'd just double check that the radio is wired to receive power full time instead of only switched power.

Comment: that would reset clock every time he turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at that radio, I would say it "may" have the clock showing all the time with the setting for it, but it most certainly won't be backlit so you probably won't be able to see it in low light conditions.